# Is it possible to know where the default PHP include_path is being set?

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, include-path

I have a bunch of PHP applications running on a remote webserver. For each of them I do `var_dump(get_include_path())` and I get this: `.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php`. Where does this value come from? I know that none of my apps deliberately change the include path. What I mean is there is nothing like `set_include_path()` or `ini_set('include_path')` in the code. There is also nothing like `php_value include_path` in the .htaccess files. To be 100% sure of it I am actually creating a brand new app with nothing more than a blank index.php (except for the var_dump) and I still get the same included path. I am pretty sure it is a global server configuration.

My server info is:
`Linux version 2.6.9-89.0.20.ELxenU (Red Hat 3.4.6-11)`

Is there any way to detect where this value is being set? I do have access to the server but I am no sys admin so my Linux capabilities are rather limited. I was hoping for some advice.

What I did so far is checked the php.ini and httpd.conf files. I know there might be more than one version of these files so to make sure I am looking in the right place:

For php.ini

- I checked the output of `phpinfo()`
- I ran this command `$ php --ini`. Besides the location of php.ini I found a bunch of other *.ini files parsed by PHP but none of them seem to do anything with paths

For httpd.conf

- I ran this command `/usr/sbin/httpd -V | grep HTTPD_ROOT`
- I ran this command `/usr/sbin/httpd -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE`

I am not sure if PEAR is installed or if it has anything to do with this. Running `$ pear` gives me `Command not found`.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at

/usr/include/php5/main/build-defs.h:79:

```
#define PHP_INCLUDE_PATH    ".:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear"
```

(Sorry, no Red Hat here, distro is Debian).